# Underutilized warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, warehouse

I have a requirement to know about snowflake warehouse usage by hour, day and week.

Want to know the number of queries queued and running by hour, day and week to know the utilization of warehouse.

Can you please help on the same with query and tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great blog post which will help:

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/understanding-snowflake-utilization-warehouse-profiling/

This page illustrates how you might better understand (visually) warehouse utilization:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html

Snowflake provides functions and views to assist you monitor warehouse usage, as outlined in the blog post, and documented in these links:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_load_history.html

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_load_history.html

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_metering_history.html

I hope this helps...Rich